# Redirect all pages to one page with RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all pages from a wordpress site to a single page in the admin area, here is the .htaccess rewrite rule I have that is not working, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I have two .htaccess files in place with the same rules, one in the root, and one in the wp-admin directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch permanent !^/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/ /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/
```

**permanent** - A permanent redirect

**!^/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/** - match any address that does not contain this in the url

**/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/** - the url I want to redirect to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use the bang `!` to negate the expression in that position. That is typically used with `RewriteCond`, but I can't verify in the docs that it isn't permitted there. In any case, you can use a `RewriteCond` and negate that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/
# Match with a 301 redirect
RewriteRule ^. wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wpct_options/ [L,R=301]
```